# JQuery UI in ASP.NET MVC5 not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC5 web application using both bootstrap and jquery and jqueryval, all working fine. I installed the JQuery UI package from nuget and modified my BundleConfig and layout as follow further down, problem is when for e.g adding a slider like, it does not display anything but the jquery-class is correcly added as an attribute.

```cs
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/customSite.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
}
```

In my view I have this in the head-tag

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

And this in the View, just before the  tag

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

The slider is implemented with:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

and script in header:

```
@section scripts
{
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider();
    });
</script>
}
```

This HTML is rendered after I removed the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") from the header having it only i the body.

```
<div class="panel-foodbrain border-bottom margin-top-100" style="height: 200px;">

<div id="slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

<span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></span></div>


</div>
```

Comment: show what actually rendered in header, when you call a page. (show html)

Comment: i have added HTML for the slider part.

Comment: Do you see any script error in console?

Comment: No, no script errors at all.

Answer (score 1):

You declared a `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in both views, one is going to cause the other to fail. Only declare the script.render once (that includes when/if you are using a layout).

Comment: I tried to remove the mentioned part from the header and updated the rendered HTML but still no luck. Right class is added to the div but no slider appear.

Comment: I can't see where your files are in the hierarchy, but I'd double and triple check all the routes to them. Capitalization and all.